# Creating kubernetes ReplicationController fails due to restartPolicy

Tags: kubernetes, restart, policy, google-kubernetes-engine

I tried creating a **Replication Controller** via an JSON file and I have mentioned **restartPolicy** as "Never" for **pod restartPolicy**.

but I am getting an error that,

**Error:
The ReplicationController "ngnix-rc" is invalid.
*spec.template.spec.restartPolicy: Unsupported value: "Never": supported values: Always**

Is there any change in v1.2 that it supports only "**Always**" as an option for **restartPolicy**? I'm confused.

I tried another scenario where I faced a strange behavior.
I specified the restart policy as "**never**" and I got the error as,

**Error:
The ReplicationController "ngnix-rc" is invalid.
*spec.template.spec.restartPolicy: Unsupported value: "never": supported values: Always, OnFailure, Never
*spec.template.spec.restartPolicy: Unsupported value: "never": supported values: Always**

As found, there are two errors in this scenario.
I don't know what is the exact problem.

The JSON file that i used to create RC is given below

```
{
  "kind":"ReplicationController",
  "apiVersion":"v1",
  "metadata":{
    "name":"ngnix-rc",
    "labels":{
      "app":"webserver"
    }
  },
  "spec":{
    "replicas":1,
    "selector":{
      "app":"webserver1"
    },
    "template":{
      "metadata":{
        "name":"ngnix-pod",
        "labels":{
          "app":"webserver1"
        }
      },
      "spec":{
        "containers":[
          {
            "image":"ngnix",
            "name":"nginx"
          }
        ],
        "restartPolicy":"Never"
      } 
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I found that the **ReplicationController** will allow only a **restartPolicy** that is equal to **"Always"**. Is this a valid one? 
Else I need to use Job for **OnFailure** or **Never** option. 
But I need to deploy a web server which I cannot deploy as a **Job** and it should be deployed as **RC**. 
In this scenario when deployed as **RC**, the container is restarting frequently which makes the web server useless.
What is the solution for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To expand on zhb's answer: while different restart policies make sense for single pods, or even for run-to-completion jobs, a replication controller's entire purpose is to keep N instances of a pod running, so saying that you don't want the pods restarted doesn't mesh great with the concept.

The part of the docs that explains this is: http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/pod-states/#restartpolicy

Comment: I got it. But the problem here is that the pod is restarted frequently.  I have been using the same container image previously with v1.1, I didn't face this problem. Now I am using the same image with v1.2, and the container is restarting frequently. I will debug and try to find the problem with the webserver if there exists any.

Comment: If the pod is restarting, there must be something wrong with it, which disabling restarts wouldn't fix. I'd recommend looking at the troubleshooting guide: http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/debugging-pods-and-replication-controllers/

Comment: I tried debugging the pod and I found that the docker daemon that is running in a node is itself restarting which results in restarting the containers.

Comment: Huh. I'd recommend rebooting the machine to get Docker into a healthier state. We have noticed a rare condition in 1.2 where Docker gets into a bad state. You can follow along here if you'd like: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/23556

Answer (score 0):

> Only a RestartPolicy equal to Always is allowed, which is the default if not specified.

quoted from here: http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/replication-controller/#pod-template